# Can't display an image with WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I'm creating an app who is a list of choices. For the 3 first choices I want to put 3 images an bellow them 3 radiobutton.

but it only show images when I write :

```
<Grid>

    <Image x:Name="sinus" Source="C:\Users\Maximilien\Documents\BFH\HBridge\HBridge\Resources\sin1.bmp" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="120,80,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Stretch="Fill"  />
    <Image x:Name="triangle" Source="C:\Users\Maximilien\Documents\BFH\HBridge\HBridge\Resources\tri1.bmp" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="320,80,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Stretch="Fill" />
    <Image x:Name="continue" Source="C:\Users\Maximilien\Documents\BFH\HBridge\HBridge\Resources\cont1.bmp" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="520,80,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Stretch="Fill" />

    <RadioButton x:Name="sinus_checkbox"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="173,200,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Cursor="Hand" ToolTip="Tension Sinusoïdale" IsChecked="True"/>
    <RadioButton x:Name="triangle_checkbox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="373,200,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Cursor="Hand" ToolTip="Tension Triangulaire"/>
    <RadioButton x:Name="continue_checkbox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="573,200,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Cursor="Hand" ToolTip="Tension Continue"/>
```

but when I send the .exe to a friend the 3 images wouldn't display..

I've tried this :

```
<Grid>

   <Image x:Name="sinus" Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/sin1.bmp" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="120,80,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Stretch="Fill"  />
    <Image x:Name="triangle" Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/tri1.bmp" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="320,80,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Stretch="Fill" />
    <Image x:Name="continue" Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/cont1.bmp" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="520,80,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Stretch="Fill" />

    <RadioButton x:Name="sinus_checkbox"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="173,200,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Cursor="Hand" ToolTip="Tension Sinusoïdale" IsChecked="True"/>
    <RadioButton x:Name="triangle_checkbox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="373,200,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Cursor="Hand" ToolTip="Tension Triangulaire"/>
    <RadioButton x:Name="continue_checkbox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="573,200,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Cursor="Hand" ToolTip="Tension Continue"/>
```

But with that , the 3 images won't even display on my PC and in the debug I got something like : Cannot find a part of the path 'C:\Users\Maximilien\Documents\BFH\HBridge\HBridge\bin\Debug\Resources\sin1.bmp'.

Maybe it's a problem with Ressources but I've set thoses images in the .resx

Thank for answer , I use VS2012 ultimate

Sorry for my english

P.S : some screen :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qM82.png

.rar of my project :

http://www.partage-facile.com/V0SQ3J1CU7/hbridge.rar.html

Comment: try putting the images in the same directory as the exe and just call it using the name of the image  `Source = "sin1.bmp"`. Or if you put an Images directory in the same directory you have the .exe file. `Source = "Images\sin1.bmp"`.

Comment: If I write your code and I put the images in the main directory I got : Cannot find the ressource 'sin1.bmp'.

If I put in the .exe directory, the app won't compile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using relative path (relative to your project folder) instead of absolute path like `C:\..`. Assuming that your project folder is `C:\Users\Maximilien\Documents\BFH\HBridge\HBridge`, this is the relative path to your images :

```
<Image x:Name="sinus" Source="Resources\sin1.bmp" .....  />
<Image x:Name="triangle" Source="Resources\tri1.bmp" .....  />
<Image x:Name="continue" Source="Resources\cont1.bmp" .....  />
```

you can also rely on Visual Studio's intellisense to get the correct relative path. When typing `Source=""` in XAML, with cursor positioned between double-quotes press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd>, dropdown will appear suggesting available paths (tested in VS2012 here)
[image]

Comment: Same as the answer of Felix Castor. But I tried your tips with CTRL + SPACE but it doesn't work here (I also use VS2012 ..)

Comment: hmm.. no idea. Works fine for me. It's hard to diagnose the problem further if I can't reproduce it here.

Comment: http://www.partage-facile.com/V0SQ3J1CU7/hbridge.rar.html

that's my project, all include (images)

Comment: downloaded your project, and surely it doesn't work. Not because of wrong path, but `Source` property of all Image control are null at run-time (for a reason I don't know). I added one new Image control and all Image suddenly works, even after the new Image removed. Check this : http://1drv.ms/1cfyxUs

Comment: Woaah , you only add this : 

sinus.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Resources/sin1.bmp", UriKind.Relative));

??

Comment: no. That one of random thing I tried, even if you remove that line, it will still working fine.

Comment: So, I didn't understand what you have done .. I need to know for the next project if I have to use images again ^^ and for my personal knowledge

Comment: ehm.. as I said in my longest comment above, I did nothing meaningful :p It's kinda *random* error, maybe wrong setting you did to the project property, I don't know for sure. To make sure, try to create new project, add necessary codes from existing project, that's it. It should be fine with relative path shown in this answer.

Comment: So I've tried .. New project WPF, copy paste all code .xaml and all code xaml.cs and adding in Ressources the 3 images... and it doesn't work .. 

I'm completly lost ..

Comment: I don't know why but I have install english language and now it work. So thank you a lot ;)